# Proposed delay in close-voting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I find that Bio.SE is kind of harsh to newbies. An old topic, but I was wondering if it would be a good idea to include a delay of 48 hours before one can vote for question closure. As of now I see many newbies posting questions that get trashed within the hour.

Of course, after editing it can be re-opened but I sense that newbies are scared away from Bio.SE by their virgin question being picked to pieces and put on hold within the hour. I know that everyone reading this question probably went through a similar process and persisted, but the process of re-opening may take quite a while, and the potential new member may have fled the scene. Further, shooting at a question is so easy.

**Editing questions as an experienced member and helping it survive is where the challenge is**. Awkward formulated questions may simply be caused by a language barrier.

**This site depends on questions.** Quite frankly asking a good question is more difficult than posting an answer.

What about introducing a compulsory delay of 48 hours or so, before a close-vote can be placed? Offensive stuff, spam and other nonsense questions can always be flagged for moderator attention.

<sup>EDIT: As an example, and nothing personal, but **just to illustrate my point** with a recent example: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31784/ecology-question . The question is **poor**, I do **not** - I repeat **not** - wish to discuss this particular question, it is **just to illustrate** the quite aggressive close-voting (put on hold after 10 minutes). I removed the discussion tag to discourage homing the discussion in on this question.</sup>

Comment: I think your example constitutes an exceptionally bad question, and it is therefore a poor example for the point you are trying to make. I didn't vote on it, but questions like that should be closed as soon as possible. It is a lazy homework question with no attempt at a solution and no initial thought. On top of that, the photographed question isn't even readable, so the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @fileunderwater: to repeat: I do not wish to discuss this particular question, it is just to illustrate the quite aggressive close-voting. A very poor question indeed, that's not the point.

Comment: I understand that. My point is that questions like the one in your example should be closed as soon as possible. There might be other examples where a delay in closing is warrented (honest attempt, but a bit unclear with poor writing), but this is not the case in your example. To me, this is a good example for why we **shouldn't** have a delay in closing.

Comment: I edited the  question. I was already fearing it would be more of a distractor. It is just to illustrate the swiftness. OP didn't even have the chance to blink or the question was put on hold. And flagging can help out if it needs quick closure.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. We got quite an increase in the questions over the last time and if we don't close bad questions, we will get flooded by them.

Comment: @Chris - questions can still be closed, but only after ~48h  - giving OP a chance to edit (encouragement), instead of immediate closure (discouragement)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Ok, then I write this differently: I think closing these bad questions fast is ok, but we should give the people the reason. And encourage editing and the putting it for re-opening.

Comment: Downvote on meta means disagreement with the question/topic.

Comment: Well, your example was closed by a moderator, so basically the same process as flagging. A meta discussion on how we should approach close-votes is reasonable (when to be more lenient etc), but I dont think there should be a "mandatory" close-delay. If that would be the case, the community wouldn't be able to quickly close really poor questions, which means that more would have to be flagged, leading to a higher workload on the elected moderators.

Comment: @Chris - *Downvote on meta means disagreement with the question/topic* - thanks! I didn't know. Meta always gives me a feeling of a mine field. This explains why :) Perhaps I just have bad ideas :/

Comment: @fileunderwater - from what I understand moderators at small beta sites are not under heavy workload and flagging is encouraged?

Comment: @fileunderwater - discussion tag re-applied. I'm very happy with this discussion and that's what it is all about I guess. Thanks for your thoughts so far.

Comment: @AliceD Maybe, but I don't think we should construct a system that only works for small beta sites. Flagging is encouraged, but should be used for the right reasons.

Comment: @fileunderwater - makes sense.

Comment: I also added to my answer on the linked post [here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/a/2878/12909).

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but I just wished to propose a solution. I guess it is not well received, but I do appreciate the comments a lot and it is another opportunity for me to ventilate my opinion about Bio's attitude to newbies.

Comment: @AliceD did you see the edit to my answer on the linked post?

Comment: @dustin - yep. Do you wish me to delete this question then?

Comment: And why close this question? Is the feature request of a delay such a bad idea it should be deleted from the records? Quite frankly I do not understand what the purpose for meta is then. Should I use the chat instead for future considerations like this?

Comment: @alice I voted to close since it is identical. Unless SE changes it programming (website), I don't see how this can be implemented. The only method would be the honor system which probably won't work.

Comment: @dustin - I'll delete the question

Comment: I don't think it needs to be deleted, but I also don't think you can since it has a positive answer. If you want, I can downvote to see if you can delete it then

Comment: We can leave it as is and I'll accept duplicate

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that close-voting can happen rather quickly, I don't think a compulsory delay of 48 hours is a good solution. At the most, a delay of a few hours to give the OP a chance to salvage the question could perhaps be a good idea, but we don't want very low-quality questions (like the one in the example) lingering for several days.